# c# colour change loop

Tags: c#, winforms, while-loop

I am trying to make an 'automatic colour change loop' in other words when someone's mouse hovers over a label, it changes colour in fast repetition, say, 300 microseconds.

```
private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Random color = new Random();
            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(color.Next(255), color.Next(255), color.Next(255)); label1.ForeColor = randomColor;
            return;
        }
    }
```

The issue is in the loop, or should I say lack thereof, I was under the presumption that the while(true) was in itself a loop there for if I kept the mouse in same place, as long as it was over the label it would act, but it only acts once, in simpler terms, I have to hover over it, then leave the area, then hover again, to get it to change colour twice, the ideal is that I can have it always changing colour, so I don't have to hover, but I can't think of a way to do that, since I need the while loop. any ideas for that second part is appreciated but not necessary :)

Comment: if you want it to change whereever the mouse is, dont use the mousehover, put it in a timer.. also, a new random each loop is excessive..

Comment: The loop is useless here because you have a return statement at the end.

Comment: You ```return``` after generating the first random color. So the while-loop is only executed once and then exits. Also: you don't do anything with the randomly generated color ```randomColor``` since you're assigning the variable but are never using it.

Comment: @BugFinder I hadn't even noticed that random to be honest, haha, but how would I put it in a timer, I am not very good coder, just coding for fun :3

Comment: Just take the color line, (and whatever you intend to do with it, as has been pointed out you arent actually using it) and place it in a timer with an interval and start it

Comment: 3 issues: You create random colors real fast; in fact so fast most of them are the same as there is no time for the random seed to change. but then 2)you do nothing with the color. nor 3) do you force a/the control/form to take the time to display. 4th issue: There is no way out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to the guys that realised I am an idiot :3

For anyone else who may want / need the code.

at the beginning of the form:

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        timer2.Start();

    }

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Interval = 100;
        timer2.Enabled = true;
        timer2.Tick += changer;
    }

void changer (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random color = new Random();
        Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(color.Next(255), color.Next(255), color.Next(255));
        label1.ForeColor = randomColor;
    }
```

Now add these, btw, I am aware that I am still issuing a new random every time, if you want to edit that, go ahead, but it works for me, quite nicely, so I am going to keep it that way.